# Webpack - how to use loader for file ending with given string?

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, webpack

I have some files called:

```
core.service.js
second.service.js
```

And I'm loading them like this:

```
rules: [
{
  test: /\.service\.js$/,
  use: { loader: 'service-loader' }
}
```

I want to rename these files to:

```
coreService.js
secondService.js
```

How should I update my "test" rule to load these? I've been trying something like:

```
test: /\service\.js$/,
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove `\` before `service`, try

`test: /service\.js$/,`

or

`test: /.*service\.js$/,`